# required: KodeinBinding<in ???, in ???, out TaskRepository>

Tags: kotlin, kodein

In exploring Kodein, I'm following the example in https://proandroiddev.com/dependency-injection-with-kotlin-kodein-koin-3d783745e48d

```
val diModel = Kodein.Module {
    bind<TasksRepository>() with singleton {
        FakeTasksRepository()
    }
}
```

I got the error

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatched:
required: KodeinBinding<in ???, in ???, out TaskRepository>
found:    (Mutable)set<(() -> FakeTaskRepository)!>!
```

What's wrong?

FYI, I use kodeIn version `6.4.0`

Add on, I have tried example from https://kodein.org/di/

```
val businessModule = Kodein.Module {
    bind<IService>() with singleton { BusinessService() }
}
```

The same things happen. Did I do something wrong? Or the documentation is out dated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I accidentally include

`import java.util.Collections.singleton`

instead of

`import org.kodein.di.generic.singleton`

Comment: Didn't understood what could go wrong with your example, didn't saw your reply.

Answer (score 1):

here a full working example:

```
import org.kodein.di.Kodein
import org.kodein.di.generic.bind
import org.kodein.di.generic.instance
import org.kodein.di.generic.singleton

interface TasksRepository {
    fun log(): String = "EMPTY"
}
class FakeTasksRepository : TasksRepository {
    override fun log(): String = "Hello Kodeiners!"
}

val diModel = Kodein.Module("diModel") {
    bind<TasksRepository>() with singleton {
        FakeTasksRepository()
    }
}

fun main() {
    val kodein = Kodein {
        import(diModel)
    }

    val tasksRepository: TasksRepository by kodein.instance()
    println(tasksRepository.log())
}
```

Comment: Your answer with the import helps. I uptick your answer.

Comment: Hopes my question helps others who got the wrong import...  and found the same error message.